# Transform frame-based to time-based movement

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, timedelta

This question isn't purely Javascript related but it's the easiest to showcase my problem.

I have an on-screen object which upon keypress should move in a particular direction. Because
a constant movement looks a bit boring, I added some sort of easing - so it bounces a little before it settles at it's new position.

The easing is calculated using this few lines:

```
  a.x = 1.2;
  v.x = v.x * 0.8 - p.x * 0.05;
  p.x += v.x + a.x * 0.5;
  v.x += a.x;
```

where `a.x` is the speed, `v.x` the velocity and `p.x` the resulting position which then gets multiplied to the on-screen object.

This works great at a fixed framerate.

To compensate for variable framerates I've added a deltatime - which based on a targeted fixed framerate - should vary the speed.

For example if the targeted framerate is 40 and the actual framerate is just 20, the value of `a.x` above is 2.4 - or e.g. 0.6 if the framerate would be 80.

Unfortunately doing it this way just works for a linear movement, so I just get strange looking movements.

To visualize it I wrote a short snippet below. The red square is what it should look like,  calculated without deltatime using the `update()` function and the green square is what I get with deltatime using the `updateWithTimeStep()` function.

What can I do to bring the velocity into play and finally get a constant framerate independent movement?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Vector {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

var speedX = 1.2;
var p = new Vector(0, 0);
var v = new Vector(0, 0);
var a = new Vector(0, 0);
var p2 = new Vector(0, 0);
var v2 = new Vector(0, 0);
var a2 = new Vector(0, 0);
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var edgeLength = 20;
var frameTime;

var targetFrameRate = 40;
var requiredFrameTime = 1000 / targetFrameRate;

var speedFactor = 0;
var prevFrameTime = new Date().getTime();

function draw() {
  context.save();
  context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  context.fillRect(centerX - edgeLength / 2 - p.x * 8, centerY - edgeLength / 2, edgeLength, edgeLength);

  context.restore();
  context.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  context.fillRect(centerX - edgeLength / 2 - p2.x * 8, centerY - edgeLength / 2 + 40, edgeLength, edgeLength);

  context.restore();
}

function update() {
  a.x = speedX;

  v.x = v.x * 0.8 - p.x * 0.05;
  p.x += v.x + a.x * 0.5;
  v.x += a.x;
}

function updateWithTimeStep() {
  frameTime = new Date().getTime();
  deltaTime = (frameTime - prevFrameTime);
  speedFactor = deltaTime / requiredFrameTime;

  a2.x = speedX * speedFactor;

  v2.x = v2.x * 0.8 - p2.x * 0.05;
  p2.x += v2.x + a2.x * 0.5;
  v2.x += a2.x;
}

function loop() {
  update();
  updateWithTimeStep()
  draw();
  prevFrameTime = frameTime;
}

setInterval(loop, 16);

document.getElementById("resetButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.x = 0;
  p.y = 0;
  a.x = 0;
  a.y = 0;
  v.x = 0;
  v.y = 0;
  p2.x = 0;
  p2.y = 0;
  a2.x = 0;
  a2.y = 0;
  v2.x = 0;
  v2.y = 0;
})
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200" style="position:absolute"></canvas>
  <button id="resetButton" style="position:absolute">
Reset
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your bounce physics to be insensitive to the time delta, you need to scale the entire update to the delta, not just parts of it.

Since your update is done in multiple stages, this is a little awkward, but *each* stage needs to be scaled to the time delta, not just the position update.  This is easier to see if you treat all stages as additive:

```
v.x += -0.2 * v.x - 0.05 * p.x;
p.x += v.x + a.x * 0.5;
v.x += a.x;

===>

v.x += speedFactor * (- 0.2 * v.x - 0.05 * p.x);
p.x += speedFactor * (v.x + a.x * 0.5);
v.x += speedFactor * a.x;
```

Note that this scaling should be done *instead* of scaling `a.x` by `speedFactor`.

---

in addition, if you want this system to stay stable in cases where your frame rate is very slow, you should limit `speedFactor` to a maximum of around `2.0` or so.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time - unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Did you try putting your modified code into the `updateWithTimeStep()` function?

Comment: Sorry, I did not try it out, I just did the math.  Does the initial reformulation work?  You need to make sure to get the sign right... and (per my edit), make sure to limit `speedFactor`

Comment: Yeah, it indeed makes the square move in the same way - independent from the framerate - unfortunately in a different way than the green rectangle. Well I guess my approach is just wrong and I need to do a combination of a fixed target position & time based linear interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make smooth animation, then you shouldn't depend on fixed time steps at all.  Instead, whenever you render a frame, you get the current time, and draw stuff at the appropriate position for that exact time.

That way, your animation will be smooth even if your frames are drawn at uneven intervals (which can certainly happen).

To do that, you need to be able to calculate the proper position at any time.

Your incremental updates end up making a position with this formula, for some D, and F:

x = e<sup>-Dt</sup> * ( cos(DFt) + sin(DFt)/F )

There's a decay component (D is for decay), multiplied by a sinusoidal component (F is for frequency)

You make the block move faster by increasing D.  You make it bouncier at the bottom by increasing F.

I've fixed your snippet to use this calculation in `updateSmooth`, making the green block a little slower than the red block with about the same bounciness.  Notice how we get to say exactly where it starts and stops, and you can easily and intuitively adjust the D and F parameters.  When you click reset, we just reset the start time to start the animation over.  There is no need to remember `a` and `v`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Vector {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

var speedX = 1.2;
var p = new Vector(0, 0);
var v = new Vector(0, 0);
var a = new Vector(0, 0);
var p2 = new Vector(0, 0);
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var edgeLength = 20;
var frameTime;

var targetFrameRate = 40;
var requiredFrameTime = 1000 / targetFrameRate;

var speedFactor = 0;
var prevFrameTime = new Date().getTime();

function draw() {
  context.save();
  context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
  context.fillRect(centerX - edgeLength / 2 - p.x * 8, centerY - edgeLength / 2, edgeLength, edgeLength);

  context.restore();
  context.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
  context.fillRect(centerX - edgeLength / 2 - p2.x * 8, centerY - edgeLength / 2 + 40, edgeLength, edgeLength);

  context.restore();
}

function update() {
  a.x = speedX;

  v.x = v.x * 0.8 - p.x * 0.05;
  p.x += v.x + a.x * 0.5;
  v.x += a.x;
}

// The shape of the graph is a sinusoid with frequency DF radians per t
// multiplied by e^-Dt.  Constraints are:
// x(t) = 1 at t=0
// dx(t)/dx = 0 at t=0
// solving the constraints gives x = e^-Dt * cos(DFt) + sin(DFt)/F
// We scale it to fit:
var startPos = 0;
var endPos = 21.5;
//Increasing F makes it "bouncier"
var F=1.5;
// it's pretty much settled when Dt=4.  Let's put this time at 600ms after start
var D=4.0/600;
var startTime = Date.now();
function updateSmooth() {
  var t = Date.now() - startTime;
  var x = Math.exp(-D*t) * (Math.cos(F*D*t) + Math.sin(F*D*t)/F);
  // scale to startPos and endPos
  p2.x = endPos + x*(startPos-endPos);
}

function loop() {
  update();
  updateSmooth()
  draw();
  prevFrameTime = frameTime;
}

setInterval(loop, 16);

document.getElementById("resetButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  p.x = 0;
  p.y = 0;
  a.x = 0;
  a.y = 0;
  v.x = 0;
  v.y = 0;
  startTime = Date.now()
})
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200" style="position:absolute"></canvas>
  <button id="resetButton" style="position:absolute">
Reset
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. Meanwhile I come up with a similar approach which also involves a fixed target destination - although that's not really what I was after. In my vision the only fixed thing would be the speed (which eventually varies depending on the framerate of course) and reaches the same destination, which is roughly 21 in the snippets (but not hardcoded using a `endPos`). Does that make sense?